# How to do a loop with variable touch -t command on mac terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
for i in {01..31}
do
    touch -t 202207$i0000 $i-07-2022.md
done
```

I have 31 .md files named 01-07-2022.md, 02-07-2022.md ... I basically want to change their creation date respectivelly to the date on their name. Is there someone able to tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thank's.

### Solution

```
for i in {01..31}
do
  SetFile -d "$i/01/2022 00:00:00" $i-07-2022.md
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `touch` command can alter the creation, modification and last access timestamps.

If you are creating a file with `touch`, then its creation (birth) timestamp and its last modification timestamp can be set with the `-t` argument provided. Add the `-m` option to constrain the change to the modification timestamp.

With `touch`, the creation time cannot be set forward of its current value, but can be decremented into the past.

The `ls` command is an easy way to see creation (birth) times instead of modification ones. Adding the `-U` option changes the output from showing the modification data to the creation date.

On macOS, the XCode Command Line Tools (when installed) provide the `SetFile` utility to manipulate changes in a file's creation timestamp independently of the modification one. For example:

```
SetFile -d "04/01/2011 01:02:03" myfile
```

changes the creation timestamp of `myfile` to the value requested. The modification timestamp remains unaltered, but can be changed with the `-m` option of `SetFile`.

```
SetFile -m "04/01/2022 01:02:03" myfile
```

Unlike using `touch`, `SetFile` can change a file's creation date forward of, or backward from, its current value.

The following script can be used to alter a file's birthtime while retaining its original modification time.

```
cat chtm.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Set a file's birth (creation) timestamp while leaving the modification
# (mtime) unaltered.

[ $(uname) = "Darwin" ] || { echo "'$0' must be run on macOS"; exit 1; }
[ $# -ne 2 ] && { printf "Usage: $0 [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS] file\n"; exit 1; }

t=$1
f=$2
stat -f "BEFORE: btime: %SB, mtime: %Sm" $f || exit 1

m=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" $f)  # capture the old mtime
touch  -t $t $f || exit 1                 # update  the btime & mtime
touch -mt $m $f || exit 1                 # restore the old mtime

stat -f "AFTER : btime: %SB, mtime: %Sm" $f
exit
```

A sample run would be:

```
touch myfile
./chtm.sh 202212311711.00 myfile
BEFORE: btime: Jan  3 12:19:21 2023, mtime: Jan  3 12:19:21 2023
AFTER : btime: Dec 31 17:11:00 2022, mtime: Jan  3 12:19:21 2023
```

As for iterating over your files, changing their timestamps based on the file names, do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in *.md
do
    mm=${file:0:2}
    dd=${file:3:2}
    yy=${file:6:4}
    touch -t ${yy}${mm}${dd}0000 ${file}
done
```

This uses [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) features to snip the components you need from the file names found.

Comment: Hello. If I do `touch -t 202207010000 myfile` then the file creation time changes to 2022/07/01 00:00. Also your solution does not include the loop.